# how to calculate the slope of a smoothed line with time as x-axis in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

My data looks like this:

```
   Time                   Type zone price no_activities   id 
1  2014/10/11 12:30:00 am  A    X    20    10              1
2  2014/10/12 12:30:00 am  A    X    20    10              2
3  2014/10/13 12:30:00 am  B    X    10     9              3
4  2014/10/14 12:30:00 am  D    X     5    12              4
5  2014/10/15 12:30:00 am  D    Y     6     5              5
6  2014/10/16 12:30:00 am  B    Y     7     8              6
7  2014/10/17 12:30:00 am  B    Y     7     8              7
8  2014/10/18 12:30:00 am  A    Y     9     5              8
9  2014/10/19 12:30:00 am  C    Y    20    23              9
```

I am able to draw the smooth lines using code below and I would like to calculate the slope of the lines.

```
subdf1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(day = as.Date(Time)) %>%
  group_by(zone, day, Type) %>%
  summarize(dailyact = sum(no_activities, na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(subdf1, aes(x=day, y= dailyact, color = Type)) + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, size =0.5) +
  facet_wrap( ~ zone)
```

Code I used to calculate the slope of the line:

```
slope = diff(subdf1$dailyact)/diff(subdf1$day)
```

However, the x-axis Time is `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` format. I get the error below when trying to calculate the slope:

```
Error in `/.difftime`(diff(subdf1$dailyact), diff(subdf1$day)) : second argument of / cannot be a "difftime" object
```

Does anyone know a way to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: For the denominator, have you tried coercing to numeric using as.numeric() ?

Comment: Hi Bill, I tried `slopes = diff(subdf1$dailyact)/diff(subdf1$as.numeric(day))` and R returned `Error in diff(subdf1$as.numeric(day)) : attempt to apply non-function`

Comment: In the denominator, try as.numeric(diff(subdf1$day))

Comment: The code managed to give a list of values which looks like `[1]        -Inf        -Inf 1092.000000        -Inf        -Inf 1886.000000 ...`. I think it's using the same y value divided by the individual x value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to calculate a slope by `zone` (because that's what you do with `geom_smooth` in your `ggplot`). In that case, I would suggest fitting a linear model to your data by `zone`, and then extracting the slope parameters.

A `tidyverse` approach would look like this

```
library(tidyverse)
subdf1 %>%
    group_by(zone) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(slope = map_dbl(data, ~coef(lm(day ~ dailyact, data = .x))[2]))
```

You don't provide enough data here for me to show a sensible output (all the slope parameters are `NA` based on the sample data you give).

---

Since your sample data is a bit too small to give sensible results, here is another example, based on the `iris` dataset.

First, let's show a plot of `Sepal.Length` as a function of `Petal.Length`. We use `geom_smooth` to show results from a linear fit to the data for every `Species`.

```
iris %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

[image]

To get the slope estimates of the linear model fits we do the following

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(slope = map_dbl(data, ~coef(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = .x))[2]))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species    data              slope
#  <fct>      <list>            <dbl>
#1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.542
#2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.828
#3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.996
```

Comment: Hi Maurits, thanks for your answer. Yes there are 2 plots by different zones. r returned `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'` using the code

Comment: @Harper I can't reproduce the error. If I use the sample data you included, the code above runs fine (producing `NA`s for the `slope` on account of there not being enough measurements in the sample data). Can you edit your post to include more representative & minimal sample data using `dput`, e.g. for only 2 zones?

Comment: sorry `zone` was supposed to be character rather than `numerical` data- please refer to the edited question. Thanks

Comment: @Harper That shouldn't change anything; the code I give in my answer works for `zone` being `numeric` or `chr`.

Comment: @Harper I've added another example based on the `iris` dataset.